# How can I change language contexts in Textmate bundles?

Tags: text-editor, textmate, textmatebundles, bundles

I'd like to get my Textmate bundles to use the correct contexts based on what I'm editing. For example I use [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui) a lot so I'd like the HTML bundle to use the YUI JS bundle instead of the standard JS one, etc.

Can anyone suggest where and what I should be editing to make that happen. Bonus points for tips on bundle editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing we are talking about here is *scope*. You'll have to edit your Bundle elements scope.

Let's take a look:

[alt text http://mtod.org/so/scope.png](http://mtod.org/so/scope.png)

Now, edit the scope to a wider one, for example use `source.js` instead of `source.js.yui`. This should be applied to every snippet, command, etc. in the Bundle. You could probably do a search & replace directly on your Bundle files.

[alt text http://mtod.org/so/edit.png](http://mtod.org/so/edit.png)

That's it. Bundle snippet triggered below.

[alt text http://mtod.org/so/yui.png](http://mtod.org/so/yui.png)